# Deserialize element name to property in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

Unfortunately an API I'm querying returns XML like so:

```
<coupon>   
  <discount_in_cents>
    <USD type="integer">500</USD>
    <EUR type="integer">450</EUR> 
  </discount_in_cents>
</coupon>
```

I have a list which I'm trying to populate.

```
public List<Discount> {get;set;}

public class Discount
{
    public string CurrencyType {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

The `Value` property gets set correctly, but I need the element name to be populated in the `CurrencyType` property (such as `CurrencyType = "USD"`). How can I tell RestSharp to populate the CurrencyType with the element name?

Comment: You can try [XmlRoot] and [XmlElement] attributes to set dependencies between classes and xml